# Wraps a vector<unsigned char> inside a stream?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a function which takes as argument an std::istream& and writes a transformed stream to an std::ostream&.

On the another hand, I have another function which accepts a vector argument.

My goal is to pass the output of the first function to the second function.

Is there something out of the box to do that ?
Otherwise, how can I easily implement it ?

Thank you

Edit : here are the 2 functions signature :

```
functionA(std::istream& _in, std::ostream& _out);
functionB(std::vector<unsigned char>& data);
```

The caller would look like :

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
std::istrstream stream_in("input message");
std::ovectorstream stream_out(data); // ???
functionA(stream_in, stream_out);
functionB(stream_out.vector());
```

Comment: What are the two functions signatures/headers ?

Comment: With a little more information I can make my answer more concrete. Some example code with a comment along the lines of "how do I convert X to Y?" in the appropriate place would be helpful

Comment: If the it's the result of the first function you are passing into the second, why don't you generate a `vector` directly in the first function?

Comment: You can't transform an output stream into a vector-like input. That would require some kind of generator concept, which doesn't exist in C++. It's hard to say what the solution is, without knowing what exactly is going into and out of these functions.

Comment: @Marcelo - if you can force the output stream to be a std::stringstream it's trivial

Comment: @Nim, right but I cannot modify functionA nor functionB

Comment: @awoodland: What if the input stream is too large to fit in memory, or never ends (like a stock ticker)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something like this might work

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
std::istringstream stream_in("input message");
std::stringstream stream_out;
functionA(stream_in, stream_out);
const std::string& str_out(stream_out.str());
copy(str_out.begin(), str_out.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
functionB(data);
```

Comment: Best! I was about to post exactly this solution!

Comment: +1. I would use `std::vector<unsigned char> data(stream_out.begin(), stream_out.end());` after the functionA() call, but that's just a minor detail.

Comment: I tried but the compiler does not find begin() and end() on std::ostringstream. I changed it to stream_out.str().begin() and stream_out.str().end(), but then I have a strange message at runtime : "string iterator are incompatible". I tried replacing vector<unsigned char> by vector::<char> but it didn't help.

Comment: @PeeWee Should work now. Forgot about the extra iterators for streams. Notice that unlike other iterators stream iterators when default constructed point to "EOF" no other iterator is required to do that.

Comment: @RedX I could make it work now, the "string iterators are incompatible" message arised because the stream_out.str() creates each time a new string object. If I first store the string in a local variable and use it for both begin and end, it works fine.

Comment: @PeeWee2201: I updated your edit by making str_out a const reference in order to avoid an additional string copy.

Comment: Details on using local const reference to prolong temporary lifetime: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/