# C++: Wrapping vector<char> with istream

Tags: c++

I want to wrap a `vector<char>` with `std::istream` (so reading the vector would be done through the `istream` interface)

What's the way to do it?

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you want to be able to do. Can you give an example of the code that you would like to be able to write?

Comment: I use a library that expects an istream to consume. But I only have a vector at hand, hence I need to wrap it somehow

Comment: Does this suffice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991697/wraps-a-vectorunsigned-char-inside-a-stream

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to do. Do you want to read a std::vector<char> from a std::istream?

Comment: Your other option if you dont want to copy is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781898/get-an-istream-from-a-char, and use `&v[0]` and `&v[0]+v.size()` as the arguments to `membuf`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448467/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494182/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You'd define a `streambuf` subclass wrapping the `vector`, and pass an instance of that to the istream constructor.

If the data does not change after construction, it is sufficient to set up the data pointers using `streambuf::setg()`; the default implementation for the other members does the right thing:

```
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT = std::char_traits<CharT> >
class vectorwrapbuf : public std::basic_streambuf<CharT, TraitsT> {
public:
    vectorwrapbuf(std::vector<CharT> &vec) {
        setg(vec.data(), vec.data(), vec.data() + vec.size());
    }
};

std::vector<char> data;
// ...
vectorwrapbuf<char> databuf(data)
std::istream is(&databuf);
```

If you need anything more advanced than that, override the `streambuf::underflow` method.

Comment: Thanks. can the ugly &*vec.begin() be replaced with vec.data() ?

Comment: Sure, same as `&*vec.end()` can be replaced with `vec.data() + vec.size()`.

Comment: Note: `std::istream` doesn't free the pointer. Better create the streambuffer on stack.

Comment: Thanks, changed. The alternative would be to create an `istream` subclass that contains the `streambuf` -- note that in this case, the (protected) no-argument `istream` constructor and the `init` method need to be used as base classes are constructed before data members.

Comment: @SimonRichter Could you please edit the second line and make it <CharT, TraitsT> instead of <CharT, Traits>? Just a minor typo. I would also make the constructor "explicit". Thanks.

Comment: p.s. check your parenthesis in the "setg(" line.

Comment: With gcc 4.7 and later, you need to use this->setg

Comment: With C++11 you might want to put in a move constructor

Comment: @PaulBruner, no, then I'd have to keep a copy of the `vector` inside the `vectorwrapbuf`.

Answer (score 16):

using Boost:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
using namespace boost::iostreams;

basic_array_source<char> input_source(&my_vector[0], my_vector.size());
stream<basic_array_source<char> > input_stream(input_source);
```

or even simpler:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/streams/bufferstream.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

bufferstream input_stream(&my_vector[0], my_vector.size());
```

Comment: I like the second one with a slightly modification for more C++'ish code: 
`bufferstream input_stream(my_vector.date(), my_vector.size());`

Answer (score 5):

Adapting the answer from [Get an istream from a char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781898/get-an-istream-from-a-char) and assuming this is what you're trying to do:

```
// Forward declarations
std::vector<char> my_create_buffer();
void my_consume_buffer( std::istream & is );

// What you want to be able to write
std::vector<char> buffer = my_create_buffer();
my_consume_buffer( wrap_vector_as_istream(buffer) );
```

You can then create the `wrap_vector_as_istream` like this (untested though) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <string>

struct wrap_vector_as_istream : std::streambuf
{
    wrap_vector_as_istream(std::vector<char> & vec ) {
        this->setg(&vec[0], &vec[0], &vec[0]+vec.size() );
    }
};
```

One thing to be aware of though. The object you've created contains pointers into the vectors memory. So if you add or remove values to the vector while having this wrapper floating around, then you're heading for a crash.

(Oh and if you up vote me, please up vote the post I've adapted this from.)

Answer (score 3):

You'd could get away with simply building a class that implements the >> operator like a stream, something like this:

```
template<class _ITy>
class RangeStreamLite
{
private:

    _ITy Begin;
    _ITy End;
    _ITy Next;

public:

    RangeStreamLite(_ITy begin, _ITy end) :
        Begin(begin),
        End(end),
        Next(begin)
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    template<class _OTy>
    RangeStreamLite& operator>>(_OTy& out)
    {
        out = *Next;
        ++Next;
        return *this;
    }


    void reset()
    {
        Next = Begin;
    }
};
```

This is a 'quick and dirty' solution, a 'stream lite', it isn't really a stream in the proper sense but it works when all you require is a superficial stream-like device. To properly create a custom stream is a little more complicated, and would require you to inherit from std::streambuf and implement the necessary features. Here are a few links worth a look:

- [Inheriting std::istream or equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231461/inheriting-stdistream-or-equivalent)
- [Deriving the C++ Stream Buffer](http://spec.winprog.org/streams/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with swapping your `vector<char>` you can use [Boost Interprocess' `vectorstream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html#interprocess.streams.vectorstream). Example:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/streams/vectorstream.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  static const char inp[] = "123 45 666"; 
  vector<char> v(inp, inp + sizeof inp  - 1);
  using ivectorstream =
    boost::interprocess::basic_ivectorstream<std::vector<char>>;
  ivectorstream is;
  is.swap_vector(v);
  while (!is.eof()) {
    int i = 0;
    is >> i;
    cout << i << '\n';
  }
  is.swap_vector(v);
  cout << string(v.begin(), v.end()) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you can't or don't want to mutate your `vector<char>`, you can use [Boost Interprocess' `bufferstream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html#interprocess.streams.bufferstream). With `bufferstream`, you don't have to swap your vector into it. Example:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/streams/bufferstream.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  static const char inp[] = "123 45 666";
  vector<char> v(inp, inp + sizeof inp  - 1);
  boost::interprocess::ibufferstream is(v.data(), v.size());
  while (!is.eof()) {
    int i = 0;
    is >> i;
    cout << i << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write a custom stream-implementation that inherits from `istream`. This can easily be done using [`Boost.Iostreams`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html) - all you'd have to do is implement a simple [Source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/source.html).

Comment: Downvote because indirection/linking to solutions instead of providing them is against the concept of Stack Overflow.