# How to initialise a stringstream from a vector char

Tags: c++, string, vector, istringstream

currently I am using  a boost char array

```
boost::array<char, 512> received_data;
std::istringstream ss_(received_data.data());
```

but what if my received_data was a `std::vector<char> received_data(512);`

how would I then get this data to my `std::istringstream ss_`?

Comment: There is no easy (and *correct*) way to do this properly. To do it right you either have to use boost or implement your own `streambuf` (which isn't *too* hard).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Wrapping vector<char> with istream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815164/c-wrapping-vectorchar-with-istream)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The istringstream takes a string, and a string can be made from two char iterators, like this:

```
istringstream iss(string(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

Comment: This makes an unnecessary copy of the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<char> receivedData(512);

std::istringstream iss(&receivedData[0]);
```

Comment: Good if there's no 0s in the data and the last is a 0.

Comment: @user494461, The iterator pair.

Comment: If there is a `0` in the middle of the `std::vector<char>` then the iterator version will only take the part up to the `0` too as far as I can tell, with that said the iterator version is preferred.