# seekg doesn't work when using istream with custom streambuf

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use a stream in order to read from a vector of existing data.

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815164/c-wrapping-vectorchar-with-istream
template<typename CharT, typename TraitsT = std::char_traits<CharT> >
class vectorwrapbuf : public std::basic_streambuf<CharT, TraitsT>
{
public:
    vectorwrapbuf(std::vector<CharT> &vec)
    {
        this->setg(&vec[0], &vec[0], &vec[0] + vec.size());
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<char> data(100, 1);
    vectorwrapbuf<char> databuf(data);
    std::istream file(&databuf);
    file.exceptions(std::istream::failbit | std::istream::badbit);
    file.seekg(10); // throws
}
```

However when I call `seekg` it throws an exception (or reports error normally if not using exceptions). Why is this? 10 is within the 100 chars of input data.

Code needs to work with both C++11 and before compilers.

Live example:
http://ideone.com/PfpW0o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::basic_streambuf::seekpos` by default returns `pos_type(off_type(-1))` according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/pubseekpos

`istream::seekg()` in order threats that as error condition, so you need to override that function in your class `vectorwrapbuf` and return actual position.

Comment: Ok thanks. Can you suggest how I do that, or is it not simple?

Comment: @NeilKirk looks like you need to validate input, call `setg()` with proper positions and return first parameter.