# C++: Wrapping vector<char> with istream such that seekg works

Tags: c++

**Not a duplicate of [C++: Wrapping vector<char> with istream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815164/c-wrapping-vectorchar-with-istream)**

Those solutions either use boost (which is not available) or do not work with `seekg` on the stream. C++11 is also not available.

`rdbuf()->pubsetbuf` method on a stringstream is not guaranteed to work and does not on VS2015.

Given a `std::vector<char>`, how can I create some object compatible with `std::istream` which reads the data directly from the vector without copying it (as stringstream would do)?

*I need to make use of the `seekg` function on the stream object.*

My attempts so far have failed or only worked on some compilers, so I am looking for the correct answer from someone who knows all the pitfalls of C++ streams.

Comment: See the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13059195/636019).

Comment: @n.m. Why? This is not a homework question. I've tried several code samples from other questions but they don't work as required.

Comment: @ildjarn Doesn't work with `seekg`

Comment: Because that's how this site generally works. You show your code, other users suggest how to fix it. This is not an absolute rule, but if you already have code, why not show it? It has nothing to do with your question being or not being homework.

Comment: @n.m. I linked to the code I already tried.

Comment: The code needs to be in the question itself, not linked to, and results and/or error messages also shown. I have no idea what you have actually tried, but I'd hazard a guess that you need to implement `seekpos` and `seekoff` in your custom streambuf class, which linked examples don't. You can implement them in terms of `setg` and `eback, gptr, egptr`.

Comment: @n.m. Yes but I don't know how to do that. That is my question. Those things are hardly simple.

Comment: You should have mentioned that. Call `setg` again with the same start and end parameters, and the new current pointer parameter. Look at `boost::direct_streambuf::seekpos` for guidance. The actual implementation is in `seek_impl`. It is as straightforward as it gets.