# tellg and seekg not working when wrap vector<char> in istream

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

As this link [https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815308/1068715] said:

I use `setg(vec.data(), vec.data(), vec.data() + vec.size());` to initialize a streambuf. 
After that, `read()` on istream working properly, but `tellg()` always return -1, and `seekg()` always failed.

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seekg` and `tellg` ask the streambuf via `pubseekoff` and `pubseekpos` to actually perform the work. The default implementation of these functions simply fail.

You need to implement `seekoff` and `seekpos` in your streambuf.

Comment: You mean override `seekoff` and `seekpos`, right? I check stringstream's implementation, it's too complicate. Is any other solution to wrap vector<char> into stream? thanks

Comment: `stringbuf`'s implementation is hard because you can mix read and write. It's not hard for a read-only streambuf.

Comment: ok, I tried to implement as stringstream does, seems working fine for now

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking this; I came across the same problem after referencing the same link.

I'd just like to add that if you're having a seekg() problem and concerned about implementing this, I would vouch for the Boost option:

```
boost::iostreams::basic_array_source<char> isrc(vec.data(), vec.size());
boost::iostreams::stream< typeof(isrc) > istr(isrc);
```

because you get this seek functionality for free straight out the box instead of having to write an implementation yourself.